# Does GemBox support column filters?

Tags: filtering, export-to-excel, gembox-spreadsheet

If I load an xlsx file that already has a filter, and then save the file using GemBox, it seems to throw my filtering cell away. Does GemBox support filtering at all? I know I can load the file in preserved mode but my intention is to create the filter in my C# app.

Comment: Corpsekicker I just wanted to let you know that in the current version of GemBox.Spreadsheet (version 3.9) we have introduced an API support for filters, see here:
http://www.gemboxsoftware.com/news/new-gembox-spreadsheet-3-9-release-with-autofilter-and-in-line-text-formatting-support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT 2015-06-15:**
The newer version of GemBox.Spreadsheet (version 3.9) does have an API support for filters, [see the version history page](https://www.gemboxsoftware.com/spreadsheet/articles/gbsversionhistory). Also, you can find [here an Excel AutoFilter example](https://www.gemboxsoftware.com/spreadsheet/examples/c-sharp-vb-net-excel-autofilter/112).

**ORIGINAL ANSWER:**
Unfortunately, in the current version (3.5) GemBox.Spreadsheet supports filtering only through preservation.